# React focusing an element programtically

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code

```
const App = () => {
   const mainContentRef = useRef(null);
   return <div>
       <button onClick={() => mainContentRef.current?.focus()}></button>
       <div ref={mainContentRef}> {...applicationContent}</div>
    </div>
}
```

However for some reason despited the ref existing and the focus() function existing on the current element, the main content div never gets focused.

This code is simplified for the purpose of asking this question, however my end goal is to construct a skip link for accessibility purpose.

Comment: How are you checking whether the `div` is focussed? (Since they don't normally have any visual indication of it.) To help us help you, could you update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button)? Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: I had a onFocus() callback on my div to check if it was focusing. However I found the issue, this was due to my content not having a tabIndex. Setting that to >=0 seems to fix my issue

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out, was able to get focus on the DIV element by setting the tab index to a number greater than or equal to 0.

Comment: Yep that will do it. Divs are not focussable by default.